# login to remote windows machine through batch file from another windows machine

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008, remote-server

My remote windows server restarts at fixed time , i need to login daily after restart , since i have scheduled few tasks in the server and they run only when loged in , please help me to automate the login process , can we do this through batch files ? like we can do the restart

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 2008 or above you can use Task Scheduler. Open Control Panel and run the Task Scheduler. Right click on Action menu and run Create Task. Create the task as usual select "Run whether user is logged on or not" and (if need) select the "Run with hightest privileges" checkbox. Then go to Triggers tab and click the "New" button. There are many conditions for run this task. Select "At stratup" and click OK. Then in the Action tab select the "New" button. There select in Action "Start a program". Click Browse button and select your script or batch file. Click OK. Repeat as necessary. Click OK again and create the new Task.

Good luck.